# How to format the values of c3.js y-axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

Is there a way in c3.js to format the axis to give it 'nice' values. Such as the X-axis starts at `0` and goes by `500` increments to the max value of 2000?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `axis.x.tick.values` (http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-tick-values)

```
...
axis: {
  x: {
    tick: {
      values: [0, 500, 1500, 2000]
    }
  }
}
...
```

Comment: how to add the tick values programmatically? I tried  `chart.internal.config.axis_x_tick_values = typeNames;` where `typeNames` is an array of `string` but it's only showing the first type

Answer (score 0):

`let categories = ['none', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'huge'];`

`....`

```
tick: {
   values: [0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000],
   format: function (d) { return categories[d/500]; }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it